# On click how can I get the closet getAttribute('data-name') with the same id

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

When I click on `#tag-list-item` it should get the closet data-name

How ever it works fine for the first one but if I click on the second `#tag-list-item` it gets the first data-name and not the closet one.

> **Question** when I click on my `#tag-list-item` how can I make sure it gets
>   the correct `getAttribute('data-name')` with same id?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#tag-list-item', function(e){
    var taglistitem = document.getElementById("tag-list-item");

    var tagbar = document.getElementById("tag-menu");

    var tagmenuitem = document.createElement("li");
    tagmenuitem.id = "tag-menu-item";
    tagbar.appendChild(tagmenuitem);

    var label = document.createElement("span");
    label.className = "label label-default";
    label.innerHTML = taglistitem.getAttribute('data-name');
    tagmenuitem.appendChild(label);
});
</script>
```

Full View

```
<div id="tag">
<?php if ($tags) {?>
<div id="tag-list-group">
<?php foreach (array_chunk($tags, 4) as $tag) { ?>
<div class="row">
<?php foreach ($tag as $tag) {?>
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-6 text-center">
<a>
<span id="tag-list-item" data-id="<?php echo $tag['tag_id'];?>" data-name="<?php echo $tag['name'];?>"><?php echo $tag['tag_name'];?></span>
</a>
</div>
<?php }?>
</div>
<?php }?>
</div>
<?php }?>

<div id="tagbar"><ul id="tag-menu" class="list-inline"></ul></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).on('click', '#tag-list-item', function(e){
    var taglistitem = document.getElementById("tag-list-item");

    var tagbar = document.getElementById("tag-menu");

    var tagmenuitem = document.createElement("li");
    tagmenuitem.id = "tag-menu-item";
    tagbar.appendChild(tagmenuitem);

    var label = document.createElement("span");
    label.className = "label label-default";
    label.innerHTML = taglistitem.getAttribute('data-name');
    tagmenuitem.appendChild(label);
});
</script>
```

Comment: The problem is because you're repeating the same `id` multiple times when they *must* be unique. Change the `id` to a `class` and it'll work fine

Comment: you are looping and having multiple element with ID `tag-list-item` you should use class and use this context to get the clicked item

Comment: `document.getElementById("tag-list-item");` gets the first item with that id - every time.  If you're using jquery, then use jquery and don't mix with js, ie use `var taglistitem = $(this)`  (or, if you really need the dom node: `var taglistitem = $(this).get(0)` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't recommend you to use `id` but class if you have multiple items.

But in all case, you can use `this` instead of select ID.

```js
$(document).on('click', '.tag-list-item', function(e){
    $('#result').html(this.getAttribute('data-name'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="tag-list-item" data-name="First">Click me</button>
<button class="tag-list-item" data-name="Second">Click me</button>
<button class="tag-list-item" data-name="Third">Click me</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because you're repeating the same `id` multiple times when they *must* be unique. You need to use a common `class` instead.

You'll then need to amend the code in your click handler to reference the element that raised the event specifically, instead of attempting to select it by its `id`. You also have an odd mix of jQuery and plain JS code which can be simplified. Try this:

```
<!-- note the 'class' is added -->
<span class="tag-list-item" data-id="<?php echo $tag['tag_id'];?>" data-name="<?php echo $tag['name'];?>"><?php echo $tag['tag_name'];?></span>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.tag-list-item', function(e){
    var $taglistitem = $(this);    
    var $tagbar = $("#tag-menu");
    var $tagmenuitem = $('<li class="tag-menu-item"></li>').appendTo($tagbar);
    $('<span class="label label-default">' + $taglistitem.data('name') + '</span').appendTo($tagmenuitem);
});
```